# Python + Selenium + PhantomJS render to PDF

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Is it possible to use `PhantomJS's` rendering to PDF capabilities when PhantomJS is being used in combination with Selenium and Python? (ie. mimic `page.render('file.pdf')` behaviour inside Python via Selenium).

I realize that this uses `GhostDriver`, and `GhostDriver` doesn't really support much in the way of printing.

If another alternative is possible that isn't Selenium, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you looked at Pypdf2? http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/tag/python-pdf-series/

Comment: @Amit: Rather extensively, as I use it all the time.  Even Phaseit themselves have said that "PyPDF2 has no knowledge of HTML".  It won't reliably render any HTML.

Comment: @Rejected do you need the screenshot to occur at an exact state during testing? Or are you just looking to load a page & render to PDF?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using selenium and special command for GhostDriver
(it should work since GhostDriver 1.1.0 and PhantomJS 1.9.6, tested with PhantomJS 1.9.8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Download a webpage as a PDF."""


from selenium import webdriver


def download(driver, target_path):
    """Download the currently displayed page to target_path."""
    def execute(script, args):
        driver.execute('executePhantomScript',
                       {'script': script, 'args': args})

    # hack while the python interface lags
    driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
    # set page format
    # inside the execution script, webpage is "this"
    page_format = 'this.paperSize = {format: "A4", orientation: "portrait" };'
    execute(page_format, [])

    # render current page
    render = '''this.render("{}")'''.format(target_path)
    execute(render, [])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')
    driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
    download(driver, "save_me.pdf")
```

see also my answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269099/952498).

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Chromedriver and Selenium? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `selenium.selenium.capture_screenshot('file.png')` but that will give you a screen shot as a png not a pdf. There does not seem to be a way to get a screenshot as a pdf.

Here are the docs for capture_screenshot: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html?highlight=screenshot#selenium.selenium.selenium.capture_screenshot

Comment: PDF is a key factor.  I can't drop down to a simple image for a multitude of reasons, such as text searching, forms, embedded media, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tried [pdfkit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit)? It can render PDF files from html pages.

Comment: I have looked into it as well. PDFKit converts HTML -> PDF, but has no further functionality.  Content analysis to determine if a page contains the desired content prior to PDF'ing sadly isn't possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same issues with PDFKit, I would want abit more advanced rendering, using it with a JS framework is quite the hassle.. :(

Comment: "Content analysis to determine if a page contains the desired content" -> Well, can't you do the content analysis yourself and if it matches then you simply send it to render with pdfkit. That's how I would do it.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then I'm not rendering the same page, I'm rendering a second retrieval of it with PDFKit, which re-fetches and re-renders.  If I go to PageA and it dynamically generates content, going back to it again means that content can be changed.  If I just save the HTML open it locally to convert, I open myself up to a lot of potential problems (relative links, hotlink protection, etc.)

Comment: pdfkit can render from string.. @Rejected

Answer (score 0):

@rejected, I know you mentioned not wanting to use subprocesses, but...

You may actually be able to leverage subprocess communication more than you anticipated. Theoretically, you could take [Ariya's stdin/stdout example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/stdin-stdout-stderr.js) and extend it to be a relatively generic wrapper script. It might first accept a page to load, then listen for (& execute) your test actions on that page. Eventually, you could kick off the `.render` or even make a generic capture for error handling:

```
try {
  // load page & execute stdin commands
} catch (e) {
  page.render(page + '-error-state.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Executing the code received via stdin would need to be done via `eval`, and from my experiences of trying to do this, it's both insecure and unreliable.  Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: While you would want to be cautious with your input (from a reliability perspective), you probably wouldn't have to worry about security since (I'm assuming) you own the process.

Comment: You could also white-list specific commands, etc for faster throws on unexpected errors. However, the best scenario I would envision is that you extract your tests (or other logic) that might occur before screen capture into a separate .js file and load that into the page (http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/inject-js.html). You could have Python at a maximum pass an arg for the specific file JS to load.