# How to run webpage code with PhantomJS via GhostDriver (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I looking for ability render pdf with `PhantomJS` via `GhostDriver`, not just render pdf. When I use next code, then page normally loaded:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('./node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

When I use next script via command line https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js then pdf generated perfectly.

Now I want execute script like `rasterize.js` (`page.render('file.pdf')`) but via `webdriver`. `webdriver` has `execute_script` method but it look like `PhantomJS` code evaluation and do not have access to `webpage` instance context. Also `webdriver` has `get_screenshot_as_base64` method, but it return only png.

I use latest versions of `selenium`, `phantomjs`, `nodejs`.

So my question how I can get access to `PhantomJS` webpage instance via `GhostDriver` and evaluate `render` method?

Comment: I'm looking for this, also... anyone ?

Comment: For just PDF generation (not `GhostDriver` or `WebDriver`) you can use `ghost.py` (need QT), found wrappers with `pyexecjs` or `subprocesses`. Also exists python packages as `pdfkit` and `wkhtmltopdf` as wrappers for `wkhtmltopdf` - it should have same results because also webkit. `weasyprint` also good but not webkit.

Answer (score 9):

There is a special way to execute PhantomJS script from GhostDriver, using the next command:

```
POST /session/id/phantom/execute
```

It was included in [GhostDriver v1.1.0](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/pull/262), so it should work since [PhantomJS v.1.9.6](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html).

Look at this example:

```
def execute(script, args):
    driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': script, 'args' : args })

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

# hack while the python interface lags
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')

# set page format
# inside the execution script, webpage is "this"
pageFormat = '''this.paperSize = {format: "A4", orientation: "portrait" };'''
execute(pageFormat, [])

# render current page
render = '''this.render("test.pdf")'''
execute(render, [])
```

Note that in OS X PhantomJS [renders web page as images](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10373) with not selectable text, due to limitations of Qt rendering engine in OS X (at least with PhantomJS v.1.9.8 and earlier).

Comment: And for non-python implementations? Is there a way to do this in Java or any other implementation other than python?