# Automate print/save web page as pdf in chrome - python 2.7

Tags: html, python-2.7, automation, pdf-generation

I am trying to automate Print Save Web Page as pdf in chrome.

I have checked the webbrowser module, but it does not seem to be intended for this purpose.

I explored  wkhtmltopdf as an alternative but when downloading the file it seems to be infected by a virus.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python + Selenium + PhantomJS render to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927090/python-selenium-phantomjs-render-to-pdf)

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me using Chrome  62.0.3202.94, ChromeDriver 2.33.506120, Selenium 3.4.3, and Python 2.7.14 or 3.6.3, on Windows 7 x64:

```py
import json
from selenium import webdriver

appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Comment: Nice workflow. Can you specify the path and rename created PDF?

Comment: @tao.hong: no, I find the newest PDF in the download directory, and move/rename it.

Comment: excellent solution, works fine for me. For java put in preference like this:     preferences.put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState",
       "{\"recentDestinations\":{\"id\":\"Save as PDF\",\"origin\":\"local\"},\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\",\"version\":2}");

Comment: The same script doesn't work in `headless` mode. Any idea why?

Comment: @Gokul No, sorry. I didn’t test headless mode.

Comment: I used the same script in Opera, but it shows up the "Save as" dialog, asking for the filename of the resulting PDF file. Any idea on how to get rid of that?

Comment: @raffamaiden Sorry, no idea. I haven't played with Opera.

Comment: for headless printing, follow: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=924981

Comment: @Gokul any update for headless mode, i am also stuck at this point.

Comment: Using the latest version of Chrome (78.0.3904.108), need to add `"account": ""` to `"recentDestinations"`.

Comment: @TAH Thanks for the heads up! I updated the answer.

Comment: any help on unix, it's not working with it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a possible solution.

The code saves an html file to pdf which is my ultimate goal.

The original post is:

> [Python + Selenium + PhantomJS render to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927090/python-selenium-phantomjs-render-to-pdf)

Best.

Comment: @MTuner, I would like to ask you about how to alter the line `render = '''this.render("test.pdf")'''`so I can render several pages using a variable name (list) and a counter and saving the file names accordingly.

Comment: Please write something useful - besides the link - in your answer. So that if the link breaks the answer is not useless.