# Selenium printing not working (Print to PDF)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, printing

I want to have selenium: open a page, sleep for 10 seconds (ensure everything has loaded), then print the webpage. Neither of the two solutions, using javascript to print the page, or using `send_keys` works.

```py
profile = FirefoxProfile(PATH_TO_PROFILE_HERE)
profile.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
profile.set_preference("print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
profile.set_preference("print.printer_Microsoft_Print_to_PDF.print_to_filename", file_location)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

driver.get(URL_HERE)
time.sleep(10)

# Neither one of these two seem to work.
# driver.execute_script('window.print();')
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "p")
```

When I manually go on to the problem page (using the profile with the preferences set appropriately), I'm able to use `Ctrl+P` and it prints without a dialogue box on where to print/what to name it.

The problem is intermittent, it will work on `www.google.com` but not some other websites? Has anyone found a way to get print to work 100% of the time?

Related Problem: [Automate print/save web page as pdf in chrome - python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136581/automate-print-save-web-page-as-pdf-in-chrome-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using selenium you can try to use this:

https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/0.4.1/

and then this code:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```