# how to automate saving web pages as PDF or HTML files using python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I have about 300 web URLS. I'll save them either as PDF or as HTML pages.
In order to have access to these web pages I must be logged in.

I've tried chrome --headless but it saves a blank page!

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="C:\\1.pdf" https://myurl.com
```

I wanted to try selenium in python but it has always opened a new Session where I wasn't logged in. I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136581/automate-print-save-web-page-as-pdf-in-chrome-python-2-7)

Could you please suggest me a solution?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried it not using headless?

Answer (score 0):

first I opened a session with selenium and I logged in manually.
Then I used the same session again (so [reconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session))
So I could access the pages in a Loop and save them

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).