# Python + Selenium + PhantomJS render to PDF - multiple files

Tags: html, python-2.7, pdf, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to addapt the code found in

> [Python + Selenium + PhantomJS render to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927090/python-selenium-phantomjs-render-to-pdf)

so I instead of saving one web page as a pdf file, I can iterate over a list of urls and save each one with a specific name (from another list).

```
count = 0
while count < length:
    def execute(script, args):
        driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': script, 'args' : args })

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

    # hack while the python interface lags
    driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST',     '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

    driver.get(urls[count])

    # set page format
    # inside the execution script, webpage is "this"
    pageFormat = '''this.paperSize = {format: "A4", orientation: "portrait" };'''
    execute(pageFormat, [])

    # render current page
    render = '''this.render("test.pdf")'''
    execute(render, [])

    count+=1
```

I tested modifying

```
render = '''this.render("test.pdf")'''
```

to

```
render = '''this.render(names[count]+".pdf")'''
```

so as to include the each name in the list using count but have not been successful.

Also tried:

```
dest = file_user[count]+".pdf"

render = '''this.render(dest)'''
execute(render, [])
```

But did not work either.

I greatly appreciate a suggestion for the appropriate syntax.

It must be very simple but I am a noobie.

Comment: Python is not php where you can simply use a variable inside of a string. You have to concatenate strings together or use a formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
render = 'this.render("{file_name}.pdf")'.format(file_name=names[count])
```

Comment: Awesome!! It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!! The link is a fantastic bonus.

Comment: An addional question...using beautifulsoup I extracted some portions of the html and replaced some text within tags, the issue is that it still renders the original html from the initial link...what do you suggest? Should I post it as a different question? Thanks!

Comment: @Diego yeah, solving it separately makes sense